# Cannot understand meaning of "identical"

Tags: plotting, function-construction, evaluation, interpolation, assignment

This came up in the context of plotting solutions to NDSolve, but I've reduced it to the following issue. This really has me scratching my head.

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]
```

ifun is now an InterpolatingFunction. I cannot plot ifun, but I can plot ifun[t] thus:

```
Plot[ifun[t], {t,0.,1.0}]
```

If I make the following assignment, I cannot plot ifun2[t]:

```
ifun2[t] = ifun[t]
```

In other words, the following statement will not plot anything:

```
Plot[ifun2[t], {t,0.0,1.0}]
```

However, if I do this:

```
ifun3[t_] = ifun[t]
```

I can plot ifun3[t]. Now, if I ask: is ifun2[t] identical to ifun[t]

```
ifun2[t] == ifun[t]
```

The answer is "True". Similarly for ifun3[t], it is identical to ifun[t]. However, ifun3[t] plots, and ifun2[t] does not! How can ifun2[t] and ifun3[t] both be identical to ifun[t] if one plots and the other doesn't?

Comment: `ifun2[t]` plots for me v 12.0.  Did you clear the kernel?

Comment: Could you send your code, and I'll try it? I am also using 12.0 and I've cleared the kernel multiple times. Another perspective: evaluating ifun2[1.0] returns "ifun2[1.0]", but evaluating ifun3[1.0] returns the number "1.".

Comment: `Plot` has `HoldAll` attribute, when you try to plot `ifun2[t]`, `t` is first replaced by some number and then rules are checked for `ifun[some number]`, but only exact pattern `ifun2[t]` is defined for `ifun2`. `ifun3` is defined for `ifun3[any argument]`. Check `Downvalues[]` of `ifun2` and `ifun3`. See also https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html

Comment: `ifun` is a pure function. To set `ifun2` equal to `ifun` use `ifun2 = ifun`. Then test with `(ifun /@ Range[0, 5, 0.1]) === (ifun2 /@ Range[0, 5, 0.1])`. It will evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how `Plot` evaluates its arguments and the difference in how the arguments evaluate.

Clearly the OP knows there is a difference between a pattern `t_` and a literal symbol `t`.

```
ifun2[t]  = ifun[t]
ifun3[t_] = ifun[t]
```

The two codes below show the difference in evaluation. On the one hand `ifun2[t]` is defined only when the argument is literally a `t`; `ifun2[0.]` is undefined, if `t` has the value `0.`.  On the other hand, `ifun3[t]` is defined whatever expression is substituted for `t`; it operates like a function.

```
Block[{t = 0.}, ifun2[t]]
(*  ifun2[0.]  *)

Block[{t = 0.}, ifun3[t]]
(*  0.  *)
```

Now `Plot` holds its arguments (it has the attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html)).  The expression to be plotted is not evaluated until `t` is given a value like `0.`.  So the first plot below is blank because `Plot` gets `ifun2[0.]` instead of a number. The second code evaluates `ifun2[t]` before passing the value to `Plot`. It evaluates to `ifun[t]` and then to `InterpolatingFunction[...][t]`; when `Plot` evaluates, it has a numeric function and generates the plot.

```
Plot[ifun2[t], {t, 0.0, 1.0}]
Plot[Evaluate@ifun2[t], {t, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

In the code below, `ifun3[t]` will evaluate to the value of the interpolating function even when `t` is replaced by a different value.  Hence, you get the desired plot.

```
Plot[ifun3[t], {t, 0.0, 1.0}]
```

In short, the definition of `ifun3[]` is to be the preferred method of defining functions.

*Hmm, didn't read the comments: This is essentially what @I.M. said below the OP.*

Answer (score 0):

My code is identical to yours.  I just copied and pasted it. The plot works, but `ifun2[1.0]` does not work and it should not work because it is not of the form `ifun2[t]`.  You need the underscore to use an argument that changes. What does work for `ifun2` is

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}};
ifun = Interpolation[points]

ifun2[t]=ifun[t]

ifun2[1.0]
ifun2[1.]
```

does not work because you are missing the underscore with the `t` so only `ifun2[t]` works.  This is all in the documentation.  Notice this, however.

```
ifun2[t] /. t -> 1.0
(*1.*)
```

works and

```
Plot[ifun2[t], {t, 0., 1.0}]
```

works for me.  I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Your `ifun3` works fully because you are using the underscore with the argument in your function.

Comment: Thanks. I see I was not thinking in the appropriate "Mathematica" way. The equivalence was not an equivalence between ifun2 and ifun3, but an equivalence between the specific cases ifun2[t] and ifun3[t]. If I use something other than t, they are no longer equivalent. I was (once again) thinking like a human who knows math, and mapping the incorrect concepts to what was going on.